# bingo card game in react native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, card

I have to create a bingo game app. In bingo a card is a 3x9 grid with 15 numbers.
The card should look like this... https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Ftombolaonline.info%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2016%2F12%2Fcartella-tombola.png&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Ftombolaonline.info%2Ftombola-napoletana%2F&tbnid=BsNQU5yHFaPetM&vet=12ahUKEwj-udicsY37AhXF2aQKHfhVCxsQMygMegUIARC0Ag..i&docid=JctVMrHOC8XL8M&w=366&h=138&q=tombola%20cartella&ved=2ahUKEwj-udicsY37AhXF2aQKHfhVCxsQMygMegUIARC0Ag

I wrote this code but it doesn't work. Returns a white screen. Any thoughts on what I did wrong?

```
import React from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, Text, View, FlatList, Dimensions} from 'react-native';


const data = [
    {key: '1'}, {key: '2'},  {key: '3'},  {key: '4'},  {key: '5'},  {key: '6'},  {key: '7'},  {key: '8'},  {key: '9'},  {key: '10'}, 
    {key: '11'}, {key: '12'},  {key: '13'},  {key: '14'},  {key: '15'},  {key: '16'},  {key: '17'},  {key: '18'},  {key: '19'},  {key: '20'}, 
    {key: '21'}, {key: '22'},  {key: '23'},  {key: '24'},  {key: '25'},  {key: '26'},  {key: '27'},  {key: '28'},  {key: '29'},  {key: '30'}, 
    {key: '31'}, {key: '32'},  {key: '33'},  {key: '34'},  {key: '35'},  {key: '36'},  {key: '37'},  {key: '38'},  {key: '39'},  {key: '40'}, 
    {key: '41'}, {key: '42'},  {key: '43'},  {key: '44'},  {key: '45'},  {key: '46'},  {key: '47'},  {key: '48'},  {key: '49'},  {key: '50'}, 
    {key: '51'}, {key: '52'},  {key: '53'},  {key: '54'},  {key: '55'},  {key: '56'},  {key: '57'},  {key: '58'},  {key: '59'},  {key: '60'}, 
    {key: '61'}, {key: '62'},  {key: '63'},  {key: '64'},  {key: '65'},  {key: '66'},  {key: '67'},  {key: '68'},  {key: '69'},  {key: '70'}, 
    {key: '71'}, {key: '72'},  {key: '73'},  {key: '74'},  {key: '75'},  {key: '76'},  {key: '77'},  {key: '78'},  {key: '79'},  {key: '80'}, 
    {key: '81'}, {key: '82'},  {key: '83'},  {key: '84'},  {key: '85'},  {key: '86'},  {key: '87'},  {key: '88'},  {key: '89'},  {key: '90'}
];

const formatData = (data, numColumns) => {
    const numRows = 3;

    const numberOfElementsRows = 5;
    const c = 0;
    while (c < numberOfElementsRows) {
        data.push({key: 'blank-${numberOfElementsLastRow}', empty: true});
        numberOfElementsLastRow = numberOfElementsLastRow + 1;
        c++;
    }

    return data;
};

const numColumns = 9;
export default class Card extends React.Component {

    renderItem = ({ item, index }) => {
        return (
            <View style={styles.item}>
                <Text style={styles.itemText}>{item.key}</Text>
            </View>
        );
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <FlatList 
                data={formatData[data, numColumns]}
                style={styles.container}
                renderItem={this.renderItem}
                numColumns={numColumns}
            />
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        marginVertical: 20,
    },
    item: {
        backgroundColor: '#4D243D',
        alignItems: 'center',
        flex: 1,
        margin: 1,
        height: Dimensions.get('window').width / numColumns,
    },
    itemText:{
        color:'#fff',
    },
   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

### Problem solved!

1. Change your FlatList code to this,

```js
<FlatList 
            data={formatData(data, numColumns)}
            style={styles.container}
            renderItem={this.renderItem}
            numColumns={numColumns}
        />
```

2. Update your **formatData** function to this,

```js
 const formatData = (data, numColumns) => {
  const numberOfFullRows = Math.floor(data.length / numColumns);

  let numberOfElementsRows = data.length - numberOfFullRows * numColumns;
  while (numberOfElementsRows != numColumns) {
    data.push({ key: `bl-${numberOfElementsRows}`, empty: true });
    numberOfElementsRows = numberOfElementsRows + 1;
  }

  return data;
};
```

#### What was the problem in your code?

a. formatData[data, numColumns] this is a wrong way of calling a function with parameters.

b.  formatData function had a syntax error.

Comment: thanks i hadn't seen the syntax errors. But so I get a 10x9 table with 90 numbers. I need a 3x9 table